# What mixed model do I need?

Tags: r, regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to fit a mixed linear model to my data.

My data has `performance` as a response variable. The explanatory variables are `trial`  and `subject`. I think `trial` is a fixed factor, numerical (it contains discrete values between 1-40). Subject contains two options, I want to include this as a random factor.

The model I made so far:

```
model1<-glmer(performance~trial+(1|subject), data=mydata)
```

This does not seem to work. 
I would like to fit a model and test for significance of the `trial` effect.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: This could be a school assignment, it is not quite clear why there's confusion. When picking random effects consider "why do you want it to be random"? "Does it make sense for it to be random"? Eg. do you have enough levels to measure variance between the groups (similar idea as calculating variance if you only had 1 observation per group) and are they random by nature? As your question is, it is not reproducible, and we cannot see what your problem is, outside the fact that subject has **2 levels**.

Comment: Hi Oliver, thank you so much for your reply. This example is not a school assignment, it is a simplified version of my own work. My problem with the model not working has now been solved. I am wondering what the minimum amount of levels is that I need for a random factor?

Comment: It is often loosely defined. The more the merrier up to the point where the algorithm simply stops converging fast enough. Ben Bolker states various places (i believe [glmmFAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) states this as an example) that 5-6 levels of random effect is needed. The estimates should become better with number of levels however, and for most asymptotic results to hold, you'll need them to increase at a certain pace compared to number of observations ([see Shun & McCullagh 1995](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2345941?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)).

Comment: What is the research for? Context is often a key question in mixed models.

Comment: Thanks again! I am looking at learning in apes. My data has a lot of measuring points per subject but contains few subjects. I will read up on the sources you suggested and find a solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad i could help. With 2 subjects it might simply be that a GLM model will work. Alternatively if suggest asking  on stats.exchange with a bit of context. It is better suited when the question is more about the theory than the programming.